# Assign values to subset of dataframe in list based on matching values of subset in two lists

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two lists (the dataframes in the list contain more columns than those two, but they are not important for my question):

```
KPI_new <- list(June=data.frame(ID=(rep("",17)), eRec= c("107349", "110878", "110024", "112188", "6187", "100420", "94436", "110165", "108508", "108773", "111859", "111907", "110704", "100413", "88995", "91644","111298") ))


KPI_old <- list(May=data.frame(ID=c(27, 30,  4,  6,  7, 20, 31,  8, 28, 25, 29, 16, 17, 18), eRec = c( "107349", "110024", "6187"  , "100420", "94436",  "88995" , "110165" ,"91644",  "108508", "105213", "108773", "102636" ,"102339" ,"100413")),
            April = data.frame(ID=c(26, 27,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7, 20, 21, 22,  8, 23, 28, 25, 29,  9, 24, 16, 17, 18), eRec=c("37866",  "107349", "93051",  "6187",   "98274",  "100420", "94436",  "88995"  ,"105107", "105109", "91644",  "105103" ,"108508" ,"105213", "108773", "85409"  ,"104145","102636" ,"102339" ,"100413")),
            March = data.frame(ID= c(2, 19,  4,  5,  6,  7, 20, 21, 22,  8, 23, 25,  9, 24, 15, 16, 17, 18), eRec=c("93051" , "104499" ,"6187",   "98274",  "100420" ,"94436",  "88995"  ,"105107" ,"105109", "91644"  ,"105103", "105213" ,"85409" , "104145", "100989", "102636" ,"102339", "100413")),
            February = data.frame(ID= c(1 , 2, 19,  4,  5,  6,  7 ,20, 21, 22,  8, 23,  9 ,10, 24, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), eRec=c("94266" , "93051",  "104499" ,"6187" ,  "98274",  "100420", "94436"  ,"88995",  "105107", "105109", "91644"  ,"105103", "85409"  ,"102252", "104145", "94559",  "101426", "100992" ,"100989" ,"102636" ,"102339" ,"100413")),
            January = data.frame(ID = c(1:18), eRec=c("94266" , "93051",  "99836",  "6187" ,  "98274",  "100420", "94436",  "91644",  "85409",  "102252", "94412",  "94559",  "101426", "100992", "100989", "102636", "102339", "100413")))
```

The list `KPI_old` contains several dataframes. The ID column is assigned based on the eRec column. So if the eRec column exists in January and in February also, the ID is the same. 
Now I want to assign IDs to the (at this point empty) ID column of the dataframe in the `KPI_new` list based on `KPI_old`.

I tried the following:

```
KPI_old_df <- do.call("rbind", KPI_old)
KPI_new[[1]]$ID[(KPI_new[[1]][,2]) %in% KPI_old_df[,2]] <- unique(KPI_old_df$ID[(KPI_old_df[,2]) %in% KPI_new[[1]][,2]])
```

This assigns the right values - the IDs of KPI_old to KPI_new for the eRec values in KPI_new which already occur in KPI_old - but it assigns some of them to the wrong rows. The order is not right.
It seems like there is something very basic which I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `match` in the following way

```
KPI_new[[1]]$ID <- KPI_old_df$ID[match(KPI_new[[1]]$eRec, KPI_old_df$eRec)]

KPI_new
#$June
#   ID   eRec
#1  27 107349
#2  NA 110878
#3  30 110024
#4  NA 112188
#5   4   6187
#6   6 100420
#7   7  94436
#8  31 110165
#9  28 108508
#10 29 108773
#11 NA 111859
#12 NA 111907
#13 NA 110704
#14 18 100413
#15 20  88995
#16  8  91644
#17 NA 111298
```

Not all `ID`s are present in `KPI_old_df`, hence some of them return `NA`.